# RTK Query - update all injectedEndpoints cache with one WebSocket connection (Best Practice)

Tags: redux, websocket, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am new to RTK query and need only one WebSocket connection for my entire application as you can see below I implemented it like an example in [GitHub](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/discussions/1615).

I need to somehow send my payload to this WebSocket by subscribing to it.
and then whenever the message comes in I update the other injected Endpoints' cache.

```
import { ApiSlice } from 'api';
import { instrumentsAdapter } from './marketSlice';

const socket = new WebSocket(process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_BASE_URL);

const socketConnected = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Connection opened
    try {
        socket.addEventListener('open', (event) => {
            resolve(event);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
        reject(err);
    }
});

export const socketApi = ApiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        socketChannel: builder.mutation({
            async queryFn(arg) {
                await socketConnected;
                const { type, topic } = arg;
                const sendPayload = { type, path: topic };
                socket.send(JSON.stringify(sendPayload));
                return { data: { messages: [] } };
            },
            async onCacheEntryAdded(arg, { cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved }) {
                console.log('arg', arg);
                await cacheDataLoaded;

                // Listen for messages
                socket.onmessage = (res) => {
                    const message = JSON.parse(res.data);
                    try {
                        // ApiSlice.util.updateQueryData('getInstrumentByRefId', arg, (draft) => {
                        //     console.log('arg', arg);
                        //     draft = { ...message.value, baseVolume: 3 };
                        // });
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log('err', err);
                    }
                };

                await cacheEntryRemoved;
                socket.close();
            }
        })
    })
});

export const { useSocketChannelMutation } = socketApi;
```

Answer (score 0):

after so much reading docs and researching I finally find this solution working but I do not know if this is a best practice or not.

Here is my not-empty ApiSlice.

```
/* eslint-disable import/prefer-default-export */
// Or from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query' if not using the auto-generated hooks
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import axiosBaseQuery from './axiosBaseQuery';

export const socket = new WebSocket(process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_BASE_URL);

const socketConnected = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        socket.addEventListener('open', (event) => {
            resolve(event);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
    }
});

// initialize an empty api service that we'll inject endpoints into later as needed
export const ApiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api',
    baseQuery: axiosBaseQuery(),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        subscribeSocket: builder.mutation({
            async queryFn(arg) {
                await socketConnected;
                const sendPayload = { type: 'SUBSCRIBE', path: arg };
                socket.send(JSON.stringify(sendPayload));
                return { data: { messages: [] } };
            }
        }),
        unsubscribeSocket: builder.mutation({
            async queryFn(arg) {
                await socketConnected;
                const sendPayload = { type: 'UNSUBSCRIBE', path: arg };
                socket.send(JSON.stringify(sendPayload));
                return { data: { messages: [] } };
            }
        }),
        channel: builder.mutation({
            async queryFn(onMessage) {
                await socketConnected;
                socket.addEventListener('message', onMessage);
                return { data: { messages: [] } };
            }
        })
    })
});

export const { useUnsubscribeSocketMutation, useSubscribeSocketMutation, useChannelMutation } =
    ApiSlice;
```

and this is my enhanced Api slice

```
import { createEntityAdapter } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { ApiSlice } from 'api';

export const instrumentsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
    selectId: (item) => item?.state?.symbol
});

export const marketApi = ApiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    overrideExisting: false,
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getMarketMap: builder.query({
            query: (type) => ({
                url: `/market/map?type=${type}`,
                method: 'get'
            })
        }),
        getInstruments: builder.query({
            query: (type) => ({
                url: `/market/instruments?type=${type}`,
                method: 'get'
            })
        }),
        getInstrumentByRefId: builder.query({
            query: (refId) => ({
                url: `/market/instruments/${refId}/summary`,
                method: 'get'
            }),
            transformResponse: (res) => {
                return instrumentsAdapter.addOne(instrumentsAdapter.getInitialState(), res);
            },
            async onCacheEntryAdded(
                arg,
                { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved, dispatch }
            ) {
                await cacheDataLoaded;
                const payload = `instruments.${arg}.summary`;

                // subs to socket
                dispatch(ApiSlice.endpoints.subscribeSocket.initiate(payload));

                // Listen for messages
                const onMessage = (res) => {
                    const message = JSON.parse(res.data);
                    try {
                        updateCachedData((draft) => {
                            instrumentsAdapter.setOne(draft, message.value);
                        });
                    } catch (err) {
                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                        console.log('err', err);
                    }
                };

                dispatch(ApiSlice.endpoints.channel.initiate(onMessage));

                await cacheEntryRemoved;
                // unsubs to socket
                dispatch(ApiSlice.endpoints.unsubscribeSocket.initiate(payload));
            }
        }),
        getCandles: builder.query({
            query: ({ refId, bucket, end, limit = 1 }) => ({
                url: `/market/instruments/${refId}/candles?bucket=${bucket}&end=${end}&limit=${limit}`,
                method: 'get'
            })
        })
    })
});

export const {
    useGetMarketMapQuery,
    useGetInstrumentByRefIdQuery,
    useGetInstrumentsQuery,
    useGetCandlesQuery
} = marketApi;
```

and I try to `dispatch` my socket endpoints from `ApiSlice` inside of `onCacheEntryAdded`.

````
 async onCacheEntryAdded(
                arg,
                { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved, dispatch }
            ) {
                await cacheDataLoaded;
                const payload = `instruments.${arg}.summary`;

                // subs to socket
                dispatch(ApiSlice.endpoints.subscribeSocket.initiate(payload));

                // Listen for messages
                const onMessage = (res) => {
                    const message = JSON.parse(res.data);
                    try {
                        updateCachedData((draft) => {
                            instrumentsAdapter.setOne(draft, message.value);
                        });
                    } catch (err) {
                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                        console.log('err', err);
                    }
                };

                dispatch(ApiSlice.endpoints.channel.initiate(onMessage));

                await cacheEntryRemoved;
                // unsubs to socket
                dispatch(ApiSlice.endpoints.unsubscribeSocket.initiate(payload));
            }
        }),
    ```
````